Error al mandar imagen por formulario en Angular 17
Tengo unos problemas al desarrollar un componente para crear un producto en una aplicación que estoy desarrollando. Al momento de que yo mando la imagen, me aparece el error:
ERROR DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on
'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename,
which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

Haciendo que la petición por POST a mi API retorne un 422, más específicamente este error:
img: ['El archivo debe ser una imagen (jpeg, png, jpg).']

Pues ya tengo validaciones en mi Api para que no acepte ningún tipo de archivo a excepción de los mostrados
¿Podrían ayudarme a solucionar este error? Sinceramente no sé cómo solucionarlo y estoy atorado en ello.
Les dejo el componente y HTML que corresponde. Saludos!
Componente
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {
  AbstractControl,
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  ValidatorFn,
  Validators,
} from "@angular/forms";
import { fadeInOutAnimations } from "../../animations";
import { ProductService } from "../../product-list/product.service";
import { Router, RouterLink, RouterLinkActive } from "@angular/router";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
@Component({
  selector: "app-crear-productos",
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterLink, RouterLinkActive],
  templateUrl: "./crear-productos.component.html",
  styleUrl: "./crear-productos.component.css",
})
export class CrearProductosComponent implements OnInit {
  productStoreForm!: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  errors: any = {};

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private productService: ProductService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productStoreForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [
        "",
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.maxLength(50),
          Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"),
        ],
      ],
      description: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      price: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.min(0.01)]],
      img: ["", [Validators.required, this.validarTipoArchivo]],
    });
  }

  get formControls() {
    return this.productStoreForm.controls;
  }

  onFileChange(event: any): void {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      this.productStoreForm.get("img")?.setValue(file);
    } else {
      this.productStoreForm.get("img")?.setValue(null);
    }
  }
  onSubmit(): void {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (this.productStoreForm.valid) {
      this.productService.createProduct(this.productStoreForm.value).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          console.log("Producto creado:", response);
          alert("Producto creado con éxito.");
          this.router.navigate(["/productos/index"]);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error("Error al crear el producto:", error);
          this.errors = error.error.errors || {};
        }
      );
    }
  }
  validarTipoArchivo: ValidatorFn = (
    control: AbstractControl
  ): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    if (control.value && control.value instanceof File) {
      const fileType = control.value.type;
      if (!fileType.match(/image\/(jpeg|png|gif)/)) {
        return { invalidFileType: true };
      }
    }
    return null;
  };
}

HTML
<div class="container login-container" [@fadeInOut]>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Registrar nuevo producto</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <form [formGroup]="productStoreForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="name">Nombre</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="name"
                formControlName="name"
                class="form-control"
                [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': productStoreForm.get('name')?.touched && productStoreForm.get('name')?.invalid }"
                placeholder="Nombre" />
              <div
                *ngIf="productStoreForm.get('name')?.errors"
                class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="productStoreForm.get('name')?.errors?.['required']">
                  El campo nombre es obligatorio.
                </div>
                <div
                  *ngIf="productStoreForm.get('name')?.errors?.['maxlength']">
                  El nombre no puede exceder los 50 caracteres.
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="productStoreForm.get('name')?.errors?.['pattern']">
                  El nombre solo puede contener letras y números.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="description">Descripción</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="description"
                formControlName="description"
                class="form-control"
                [ngClass]="{
                    'is-invalid':
                      submitted && formControls['description'].errors
                  }"
                placeholder="Descripción" />
              <div
                *ngIf="submitted && formControls['description'].errors"
                class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="formControls['description'].errors['required']">
                  La descripción es obligatoria.
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="formControls['description'].errors['maxlength']">
                  La descripción no puede exceder los 50 caracteres.
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="errors.description">
                  {{ errors.description[0] }}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="price">Precio</label>
              <input
                type="file"
                type="number"
                id="price"
                formControlName="price"
                class="form-control"
                [ngClass]="{
                    'is-invalid':
                      submitted && formControls['price'].errors
                  }"
                placeholder="Precio" />
              <div
                *ngIf="submitted && formControls['price'].errors"
                class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="formControls['price'].errors['required']">
                  El precio es obligatorio.
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="formControls['price'].errors['min']">
                  El precio no puede ser inferior a 0.01.
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="errors.price">{{ errors.price[0] }}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="img">Imagen</label>
              <input
                type="file"
                id="img"
                formControlName="img"
                (change)="onFileChange($event)"
                class="form-control"
                [ngClass]="{
                    'is-invalid':
                      submitted && formControls['img'].errors
                  }" />
              <div
                *ngIf="submitted && formControls['img'].errors"
                class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="formControls['img'].errors['required']">
                  La imagen es obligatoria.
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="errors.img">{{ errors.img[0] }}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
              Crear producto
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


Copiar y pegar da lugar a errores:  <input type="file"                   type="number". Tu input es tipo archivo o numérico? Corrige tu html y mira si sigue dándote errores. Por otro lado, el error es bastante descriptivo, estás intentando setear un valor programáticamente a un campo de tipo "file" y ahí solo puedes setear de esa manera un string vacío, tú estás seteando NULL o intentando meterle un archivo... para qué me pregunto, si ese file ya lo estás leyendo del propio input!

Dato adicional: if (!fileType.match(/image\/(jpeg|png|gif)/)) { en esa lista incluye jpg

Cuando haces el bind del input:file con el reactive form, al seleccionar una imagen esto te retorna un string con el fake path.
Debes quitar el formControlName="img", para que no haya conflicto entre capturar la imagen seleccionada y que se le asigne un string al input. El resto de la lógica está bien, ya que el control img de tu form no está vinculado a ningún elemento HTML, pero de forma programática le estarás pasando la imagen que capturas.
P.D.: el setValue(null) no es el error. Es una forma válida de borrar el contenido, aunque por temas de consistencia, en vista de que el valor por defecto de dicho control es un string vacío, te recomendaría manejarlo de esa forma también.

Componente
onFileChange(event: any): void {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    this.productStoreForm.get('img')?.setValue(file);
  } else {
    this.productStoreForm.get('img')?.setValue('');
  }
}

HTML
<input
  type="file"
  id="img"
  (change)="onFileChange($event)"
  class="form-control"
  [ngClass]="{
    'is-invalid':
      submitted && formControls['img'].errors
  }"
/>

